# Veeva CLM: No CLM available after syncing to CRM

Tags: salesforce, salesforce-lightning, veeva

I've tried for hours to sync the CLM presentation to CRM. But i can recive the presentation on ipad CRM.

What I've tried:

1. I've created as "Multichannel Presentatio"n (Binder) with 29
   "Presentation Slides". Reditions automatically created -> thumbnails created automatically
2. Moved each Slide trough the Lifecycle (In my Case (Darft -> Staged -> Approved).
3. CLM Content -> Yes
4. Product -> Cholecap
5. Approved the whole presentation binder
6. Doing a Force full Refresh in CRM Saleforce CLM Admin Tab
7. Open CRM on Ipad and sync again -> sync ready
8. Click on Media on Ipad in Veeva CRM -> no presentation available

Can someone give me a hint?
I've alread spend days in reading the documentation... but nothing works.

Answer (score 0):

In Salesforce CLM Admin you have to edit CRM Connection and set Connection type from "All" to "Binder and Slide".

Answer (score 0):

First check is your Presentation available in the CRM using admin account.

If yes then this is could config issue for viewing in particular account if no then issue with vault level.